# Using MariaDB's COLUMN_GET() in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

MariaDB allows [dynamic columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dynamic-columns/), which are sparsely populated sets of data accessed by `COLUMN_ADD()` and `COLUMN_GET()` functions.

However, we cannot find a way to use dynamic columns with SQLAlchemy. We have tried:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

...

query = session.query(
    func.COLUMN_GET(DynamicInfo.dyn_col, 256)
).filter(
    DynamicInfo.index_id == index
)
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT COLUMN_GET(dyn_info.dyn_col, %(COLUMN_GET_2)s) AS `COLUMN_GET_1`
FROM dyn_info
WHERE dyn_info.index_id = %(index_1)s
```

The problem is that this is invalid syntax for `COLUMN_GET()`; it must include the type as well as the value. We cannot figure out how to get `COLUMN_GET(dyn_info.dyn_col, 256 AS INT)`, without writing the SQL ourselves (which would negate most of the benefits of using SQL alchemy in the first place).

---

We have also looked at a lot of the SQLAlchemy source code at how columns are handled, hoping that we could copy that format and have custom comparators defined. The problem lies in the fact that dynamic columns require the index parameter when they are called, which would make a proper definition of the COLUMN_GET() function by far the easiest/cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer can be obsoleted by future development of SQLAlchemy, but I found it useful to build my own clause elements using SQLAlchemy means. Perhaps, the best example can be found from [sqlalchemy-fulltext-search](https://github.com/mengzhuo/sqlalchemy-fulltext-search/blob/dev/sqlalchemy_fulltext/__init__.py) project.

By subclassing `ClauseElement` and compiling it, one can make almost any additions to the SQLAlchemy arsenal, not just functions. The example also shows how to instrument classes if that is needed (in the linked example, to define a special index).

Also, this way one can add dialect-specific syntaxes.

I think, you will find all needed ingredients for your case.

Of course, SQLAlchemy allows to pass any SQL text, but I guess Pythonic syntax is what is interesting here.

Comment: I had actually just finished doing this! For our purposes, it was cleanest to create our own `Function`, but the only difference is that it has special handling of the `ClauseElement`. Thanks for the answer, though.